# Bug allowing question draft to easily be discarded

Tags: bug, asking-questions

There is some serious bug in the tag input bar, which can easily lead to the question draft to be discarded (yes, just happened to me, still miffed). Follow these steps to reproduce:

1. Type question and title.
2. Enter tags.
3. Enter a non-existing tag.
4. Press Enter.

For some reason at this point it looks like I'm trying to leave the page, and a prompt pops up asking me whether I'm sure I want to discard my draft. Well, guess what, since Enter in the tag bar has a meaning, it's super easy to accidentally fumble this and confirm this dialog.

[image: Are you sure you want to discard your draft?]

**The bug is in pressing Enter leading to this dialog for whatever reason.**

Additional information:

- Safari 12 on macOS
- I'm part of a Team, so I have an additional "confirm you want to publish a public question" checkbox (I suppose, not sure if relevant)
- problem can't be reproduced on Meta

Comment: I can't repro on Chome/Win10. I do get a fancy dialog that asks me to confirm I want to create a new tag. I'm also on a Team.

Comment: No repro in Safari, Chrome, or Firefox on macOS, I get the same dialog rene mentioned. I'm not in a team though.